# Не работает Wrapping в TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Реализую лог **на подобии** [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743804/implementing-a-log-viewer-with-wpf)

Сделал **аналогичный** `DataTemplate`:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type core:TimedLog}">
        <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Date" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Message" Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat={}{0:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss:}}" 
            Grid.Column="0"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Column="1"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

И по аналогии сделал само пространство лога (В основном только вынес `ScrollViever` за `ItemControl`, что бы прокрутка стала не по элементам прыгать, иначе развернутые последующие уровни лога даже не просмотреть)

```
        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Padding="8,5,0,5" Margin="0">
                <ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Template>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

И всё вроде бы хорошо, но строка лога перестала подстраивать высоту и обрезается текст на первой строке. Подумал, может из-за того что вынес `ScrollViever`, `TimedLog` стал выходит за пределы экрана, но проверил в Реалтайме и ширина правильная. Просто перестал переносить. В чём может быть проблема?

**UPD:**
Если в `TextBlock` добавить фиксированную ширину, то перенос работает.

Comment: А не могли бы вы обрезать пример до минимума? Например, внешний `Grid` — он важен для воспроизведения проблемы?

Comment: @VladD, ну может и был важен, малоли. Обновил

Comment: Ну, так вы бы и проэкспериментировали. Иначе это придётся делать тому, кто будет пытаться ответить.

Comment: @VladD я не думаю что он как то важен, но малоли там нужно было что-то явно указать.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ таился в этом блоке:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Date" Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Message" Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Во втором `ColumnDefinition` нужно было убрать `SharedSizeGroup="Message"` и `Width="Auto"` и автоперенос стал работать:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Date" Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```